# Error launching Abaqus CAE

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, xserver

When I launch Abaqus CAE (actually the GUI part of abaqus) I get following error:

```
david@xxx:/opt/abaqus/Commands$ ./abaqus cae
Abaqus License Manager checked out the following license(s):
"cae_xx" release 6.14 from Flexnet server xxx.yyy.zz
<x out of y licenses remain available>.


terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nex_PrimException<ipc_IPCMsgErrorTypeEnm, 1>'
Abaqus Error: Abaqus/CAE Kernel exited with an error.
```

This error appears pretty much the same as the error described [here](https://polymerfem.com/forum/finite-element-modeling/computer-software-aa/3288-glx-error-when-launching-abaqus-on-debian). In fact, if I run `glxinfo -i` I also get an error:

```
david@igtdodav:/opt/abaqus/Commands$ glxinfo -i
name of display: :1
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

However, the solution proposed in that website:

> Simply add `+iglx` to the line: `xserver-command=X -core +iglx` in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf`

does not work for me. Also launching with `-mesa` flag or with `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae -mesa` does not work.

Do you have any idea about this issue? I run ubuntu 16.04.02 64bit on a Desktop PC with nvidia Quadro K420 with 375.39 driver. I just updated the driver from the tested 367 to check if the problem was solved, but no.

Comment: I then switched again to the tested (from ubuntu devs) drivers and last week I got the update to nvidia 375.39. Since then I can run abaqus with `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae -mesa` and it works